# Exclude dlls from build in Unity3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, dll, dependencies, size

I build my app into apk file and get editor log that makes me kind of dissapoinmented.

There are dependencies in my build: Mono.Security.dll System.Core.dll System.dll mscorlib.dll UnityEngine.dll UnityEngine.Networking.dll Assembly-Sharp.dll

And I tend to think that by using mscorlib into stripping level could make me free of System.dll.

I use nothing special but only IEnumerators and primitive types.

Could someone suggest what can I do for exlude non-using dlls ?

Thank you!

Comment: it's a good question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is that UnityEngine.dll personally uses the System.dll. So, that is it. There is no opportunity to avoid System.dll. By the way, do not select "use mscorlib" in stripping level in settings, because Unity adds the mscorlib.dll and actully do not use it.